# How long time would it take to decrypt a sha256 hash?

Tags: sha256

how to crack this hash if we know it have a length of 64 caracters and no upcases caracters and no special caracters only numbers and lowercase?
if we could make about 1.000.000 guesses per second?

Comment: Sounds like some multiplications to find out by yourself?

Comment: what i found out is that 1.000.000 guesses is realistic, that's it ;(

Answer (score 9):

The phrase "decrypt a sha256 hash?" is problematic, a hash is not encryption thus it can't be decrypted. What can be done is computed hashes and try to find some input that creates the same hash. But that hash may not be the initial value, it may be some other value that happens to have a matching hash.

Past the end of human life on the earth:

12,700,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years.

((36^64)/100000000)/31536000

36 character in set
64 number of characters
1,000,000 attempts/second
~315,36,000 seconds/year

There will also be around 36^64 / 2^256 or 34,600,000,000,000,000,000,000 collisions found.

Note that the possible combinations of the string are greater than the number of possible hashes. Thus it is clear that something is being lost when the hash is computed as exemplified by the number of potential collisions.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot decrypt a hash, because a hash is not encryption, it is a hash.

It is impossible. The question how long it takes to do an impossible task is meaningless. You can only decrypt something that is encrypted. A hash doesn't encrypt, it hashes. You cannot decrypt a hash because it isn't encrypted in the first place.

A hash function is not injective. It simply *cannot be reversed*. Period.

A hash function maps a large (potentially infinite) input space to a smaller (usually finite) output space. The Pigeonhole Principle tells us that when we map a larger space to a smaller space, there must be at least some elements of the larger input space that map to the same element of the smaller output space. Since there are potentially multiple inputs that map to the same output, the function cannot be reversed. The information which of the multiple inputs was mapped to the output is lost forever.

A hash cannot be decrypted.

Comment: i want just asking how long it would take with brute force

Comment: It is impossible. The question how long it takes to do an impossible task is meaningless. You can only decrypt something that is encrypted. A hash doesn't encrypt, it hashes. You cannot decrypt a hash because it isn't encrypted in the first place.

Comment: The above answer is not true. Decoding a hash can take up to the end of the universe but if the input is short you could look it up using a rainbow table. It just takes exponentially more storage space for extra word/character of the input string

Comment: @Caveman: it is impossible to decrypt a hash, because you can only decrypt something that was encrypted, and a hash doesn't encrypt, it hashes, that is why it is called a hash. Hash functions are *by definition* not injective. "Injective" is just a fancy term for "can be reversed". If something can be reversed, it cannot be a hash, if something is a hash, it cannot be reversed. That is true *by definition*. It is guaranteed by the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Let's say that I hash every word in the dictionary. Store the hashes in a table with { id = hash, str = 'hashed string' } then I'm pretty sure that I can find out what **some** hashes are. Whether it's possible or not depends on the input, this is why [rainbow tables](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rainbow_table) exist.

Comment: @Caveman: Let's make the example even simpler. Let's use the stupidest, shortest hash possible: the hash is 1 if the input is odd, 0 if the input is even. If I tell you that the output is 0, can you tell me the input?

Comment: I see where you're going with this. If the hash is short compared to the input then it's impossible (like a checksum of a PDF can't contain a PDF). However, if we have the input [selected from a] finite list of words, such as the dictionary and it uses sha256, I could find out what word was used as input.